# Implementing FactoryPattern without using an Interface C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, factory-pattern

I have a requirement of refactoring the code where I have multiple classes and the object of the classes need to be created dynamically depending upon the  user request. Now the classes are all there and have no common methods within them that match each other. So I cannot add an interface to it and create a factory class that will return the interface reference referencing the actual class. Is there a way with generics or any other way to refactor this to be able to create objects dynamically. The approach we have now is that there is a main class where the object of each class is instantiated and all methods are being called. Can we implement a factory pattern without an interface or any solution to my scenario ? Please.

Adding sample code to explain the scenario.

```
 public interface ITest
{
    string TestMethod1(string st, int ab);
    int TestMethod2(string st);
    void TestMethod4(int ab);
    float ITest.TestMethod3(string st);
}
public class Class1 : ITest
{
    public string TestMethod1(string st, int ab)
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
    public void TestMethod4(int ab)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public int TestMethod2(string st)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public float TestMethod3(string st)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
 public class Class2 : ITest
{

    float ITest.TestMethod3(string st)
    {
        return float.Parse("12.4");
    }

    void ITest.TestMethod4(int ab)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public string TestMethod1(string st, int ab)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public int TestMethod2(string st)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
 public class Main
{
    ITest test = null;

    public ITest CreateFactory(TestType testType)
    {
        switch(testType)
        {
            case TestType.Class1:
               test = new Class1();
                break;
            case TestType.Class2:
                test = new Class2();
                break;
        }
        return test;
    }
}

enum TestType
{
    Class1,
    Class2
}
```

So, as in above, I can't have the interface because no common methods are in it. So what other solutions I can have, if I have an empty interface or abstract method, how will that help. Even if I put one common method in the interface and all classes implement it, since I am passing the reference to the interface, I can only access the common method from the interface reference.

My idea is to use something like the below, but not sure what the return type would or should be defined as.

```
 public T CreateFactory(TestType testType)
    {
        switch(testType)
        {
            case TestType.Class1:
               return GetInstance<Class1>("Class1");

            case TestType.Class2:
                return GetInstance<Class1>("Class2");

        }
        return null;
    }
    public T GetInstance<T>(string type)
    {
        return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(type));
    }
```

How do I define T here in the return is my concern and how can I invoke it, if anybody can help with that, then I think I am close to the solution.

Answer to my problem

```
public static T CreateFactory<T>()
    where T: IFactory, new()
{
    return new T();
}
```

Comment: create a post on http://codereview.stackexchange.com
OR paste your code here
otherwise this is just theoretical discussion

Comment: How do you know later (after objects created) how to handle or which methods need to be called? That logic can help solve your problem.

Comment: my problem in short is this. I have a class which creates objects of the specified type and returns the created object, however in order to return it I need to cast it or convert it or have an interface which is implemented by all my classes and then return that interface ref, but I cannot have an interface here bcoz there are no common methods, so what can I do in this case ?

Comment: You have a class `FactoryLikeClass` which returns objects based on some input `userInput`. These objects does not have common methods. At the object creation point in `FactoryLikeClass` you know which method(s) will be called on the newly created object?

Comment: they are invoked dynamically, there may be 4-5 methods in each class and depending on the requirement one of the methods will be called. I don understand what you mean by "I KNOW WHICH METHODS WILL BE CALLED."

Comment: The type system do not allow this. You have to provide something for the compiler to allow to do their job. It might be usable scenario in a dynamically typed language tho.

Comment: Please see the update with the answer I found using generics.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not saying totally understand the problem, but give it a shot...

Factory like class that you have:

```
class Factory
{
    public static Visitable Create(string userInput)
    {
        switch (userInput)
        {
            case nameof(ClassA):
                return new ClassA();
            case nameof(ClassB):
                return new ClassB();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Types that you have to create:

```
class ClassA : Visitable
{
    public void M1(){}
    public override void Accept(Visitor visitor){visitor.Visit(this)}
}

class ClassB : Visitable
{
    public void M2(){}
    public override void Accept(Visitor visitor){visitor.Visit(this)}
}
```

Usage of the code:

```
var visitor = new Visitor();
var obj = Factory.Create("ClassA");
obj.Accept(visitor);
```

And the missing parts:

```
class Visitor
{
    public void Visit(ClassA obj){ obj.M1(); } // Here you have to know what method will be called!
    public void Visit(ClassB obj){ obj.M2(); } // Here you have to know what method will be called!
}

abstract class Visitable
{
    public abstract void Accept(Visitor visitor);
}
```

This is called the Visitor pattern. If you know what methods need to be called Visitor.Visit than that is what you want.

Comment: this is new to me, but I don think it will work for me. There are lot of classes and they keep getting added, so I have to keep making changes here, if I go for factory all I need is to add a switch and the method in interface. but thanks for taking the time to explain it so well..

Comment: At least now you know what is the right way :) I don't know any other pattern/technique that can help you. Maybe some black magic...
This is a good site about the patterns: http://www.dofactory.com/net/design-patterns
Worth to look it up!

Comment: Pattern matching but it's a C# 7 feature, you have to wait for it.

Answer (score 0):

<del>I don't entirely understand your question but a basic assertion is wrong.</del> I am concerned with your design given the basis of your question.

Regardless, my proposed solution:

You are saying that you don't have a common object (indirect, directly you stated: "I can't have the interface because no common methods are in it."

`object` is the common element.

I don't condone this but you could create a factory object that just returned `object` as the data type. The problem with this is you then have to cast it after the object creation which you may not mind...

```
internal class MyFactory
{
    internal object CreateItem1() { return ...; }
    internal object CreateItem2() { return ...; }
    internal object CreateItem2(ExampleEnum e) 
    {
        switch(e) 
        {
            case e.Something:
               return new blah();
            default:
               return new List<string>();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: what I have is a simple factory pattern, not sure why anybody is not able to understand it, my only change that is required here is to replace the interface with something else, like a generic may be, return an object of type T, but I don know how to implement it.

Comment: That is my suggestion. Use `object` which is the base of all object inside of the CLR (.NET) regardless of declaration (it's implicit). In my case, I don't understand the purpose. If you can't predict the type of object, you may not be designing your objects correctly. It's a very big topic but regardless if your reason, my answer should be adequate based on what you've commented with.

Comment: but at the receiving end how would I know which type to convert it back to from the object I send ?

Comment: This is what concerns me (and hence my note on understanding). In Python, for example, that is a possible problem. In the CLR that can't be a problem since you need to know that at compile time. If, as the programmer, you don't know what you are receiving in order to cast it, how would you know what methods and properties are available in order to use the object?

Comment: to answer your question, in the above code that i posted, the createFactory method, will it know what object it will return ? it is dependent on the input parameter rt ? I can tell you what all objects it can create, but I cant tell you which object it will return at run time.

Comment: So, bottom line is you want a method that you tell it what type and it returns a new instance of that type? Factory pattern isn't for this. What you described is custom implementation to replace/wrap the `new` keyword... which isn't purposeful. Just use the new keyword.

Comment: Please see my update for the answer...thank you for the time and effort in helping me find the solution.